# How would I scrape multiple tables using indices with BeautifulSoup?

Tags: python, html, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

I am trying to scrape this URL so I can only grab certain indices. In this case, I example shown I can scrape index 6 which will give me any url that starts with /wiki/. which will give me all the TLDs that start with an A. I would like to grab all of the indices that I find relevant to my task.

As of right now I have tried list them as such [6, 7, 8, etc] and in quotations. I have not working much with lists though, and I need to spend some more time learning.

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup 

page = requests.get('https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_Internet_top-level_domains')
soup = BeautifulSoup(page.text, 'lxml')

table = soup.findAll('table')[6]
for record in table.findAll('tr'):
    for data in record.findAll('td'):
        for link in data.select("a[href^='/wiki/.']"):
            links = link.contents[0]
            print(links)
```

However, as I am new to programming I am not sure how to add multiple indices aside from 6. These are the errors I am receiving:

```
======= RESTART: /run/media/sean/The Continuum/Python/wikinamelist.py =======
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/run/media/sean/The Continuum/Python/wikinamelist.py", line 7, in <module>
    table_data = soup.find_all('table')["6", "7"]
TypeError: list indices must be integers or slices, not tuple
>>> 
======= RESTART: /run/media/sean/The Continuum/Python/wikinamelist.py =======
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/run/media/sean/The Continuum/Python/wikinamelist.py", line 7, in <module>
    table_data = soup.find_all('table')[6, 7];
TypeError: list indices must be integers or slices, not tuple
>>> 
======= RESTART: /run/media/sean/The Continuum/Python/wikinamelist.py =======
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/run/media/sean/The Continuum/Python/wikinamelist.py", line 7, in <module>
    table_data = soup.find_all('table')[6, 7, 8];
TypeError: list indices must be integers or slices, not tuple
```

As you can see above I have multiple methods which I have tried shown in the error message.

Any feedback would be appreciated, thank you!

Answer (score 0):

You might be able to use comma separated nth-of-type

```
table:nth-of-type(6), table:nth-of-type(7), table:nth-of-type(8)
```

So,

```
tables = soup.select('table:nth-of-type(6), table:nth-of-type(7), table:nth-of-type(8)')
```

Then

```
for table in table:
```

You could also condense

```
links = [item['href'] for item in soup.select("table:nth-of-type(6) [href^='/wiki/.'], table:nth-of-type(7) [href^='/wiki/.'], table:nth-of-type(8) [href^='/wiki/.']")
```

You might also be able to swop out the type selector of `table` for a class selector e.g. `.wikitable`. This would be faster.

---

**pd.read_html:**

If `pd.read_html` returns tables then you could just index/slice into that list to get required tables.

Answer (score 0):

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup 

page = requests.get('https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_Internet_top-level_domains')
soup = BeautifulSoup(page.text, 'html.parser')

a = soup.select('table:nth-of-type(5) td:first-of-type')
b = soup.select('table:nth-of-type(6) td:first-of-type')
c = soup.select('table:nth-of-type(7) td:first-of-type')
d = soup.select('table:nth-of-type(8) td:first-of-type')
e = soup.select('table:nth-of-type(9) td:first-of-type')
f = soup.select('table:nth-of-type(10) td:first-of-type')
g = soup.select('table:nth-of-type(11) td:first-of-type')
h = soup.select('table:nth-of-type(12) td:first-of-type')
ij = soup.select('table:nth-of-type(13) td:first-of-type')
k = soup.select('table:nth-of-type(14) td:first-of-type')
l = soup.select('table:nth-of-type(15) td:first-of-type')
m = soup.select('table:nth-of-type(16) td:first-of-type')
n = soup.select('table:nth-of-type(17) td:first-of-type')
opq = soup.select('table:nth-of-type(18) td:first-of-type')
r = soup.select('table:nth-of-type(19) td:first-of-type')
s = soup.select('table:nth-of-type(20) td:first-of-type')
t = soup.select('table:nth-of-type(21) td:first-of-type')
uv = soup.select('table:nth-of-type(22) td:first-of-type')
wxyz = soup.select('table:nth-of-type(23) td:first-of-type')


print(a, b, c, d, e, f, g, h, ij, k, l, m, n, opq, r, s, t, uv, wxyz)
```

This is the simplest way to scrape multiple lists on the page. This will individually target both the first column, and iterate through every table.

The answer above did help with my question! However, I made an alteration to the suggestion above. Rather than condensing the code as suggested I instead created a list of variables which would select the table I asked for. Then I printed the information from the variables to STDout. This code is more readable, and more modular.

The variables also correspond to the name of the tables.

Thanks for the help, this became super simple after your suggestion.